# What do parentheses in a C variable declaration mean?

Tags: c, syntax

Can someone explain what this means?

```
int (*data[2])[2];
```

Comment: This Microsoft link might help. (Or it might just make your brain explode) [Interpreting More Complex Declarators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4.aspx)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**What are the parentheses for?**

In C brackets [] have a higher precedence than the asterisk *

**Good explanation from Wikipedia:**

> To declare a variable as being a
>   pointer to an array, we must make use
>   of parentheses. This is because in C
>   brackets ([]) have higher precedence
>   than the asterisk (*). So if we wish to declare a pointer to an array, we need to supply parentheses to override this:

```
double (*elephant)[20];
```

> This declares that elephant is a
>   pointer, and the type it points at is
>   an array of 20 double values.
>
> To declare a pointer to an array of
>   pointers, simply combine the
>   notations.

```
int *(*crocodile)[15];
```

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations).

**And your actual case:**

```
int (*data[2])[5];
```

data is an array of 2 elements.  Each element contains a pointer to an array of 5 ints.

So you you could have in code using your 'data' type:

```
int (*data[2])[5];
int x1[5];
data[0] = &x1;
data[1] = &x1;

data[2] = &x1;//<--- out of bounds, crash data has no 3rd element
int y1[10];
data[0] = &y1;//<--- compiling error, each element of data must point to an int[5] not an int[10]
```

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 18):

There is a very cool program called "cdecl" that you can download for Linux/Unix and probably for Windows as well.  You paste in a C (or C++ if you use c++decl) variable declaration and it spells it out in simple words.

Comment: With a name like @sixlettervariables, I'm assuming you're even more old-school than me.  Please tell me you remember Henry Spencer's commandments?

Comment: It's a website that you can just use now: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 6):

If you know how to read *expressions* in C, then you're one step away from reading complicated declarations.

What does

```
char *p;
```

really mean? It means that `*p` is a char. What does

```
int (*data[2])[5];
```

mean? It means that `(*data[x])[y]` is an int (provided 0 <= x < 2 and 0 <= y < 5). Now, just think about what the implications of that are. `data` has to be... an array of 2... pointers... to arrays of 5... integers.

Don't you think that's quite elegant? All you're doing is stating the type of an expression. Once you grasp that, declarations will never intimidate you again!

The "quick rule" is to start with the variable name, scan to the right until you hit a ), go back to the variable name and scan to the left until you hit a (. Then "step out" of the pair of parentheses, and repeat the process.

Let's apply it to something ridiculous:

```
void **(*(*weird)[6])(char, int);
```

`weird` is a pointer to an array of 6 pointers to functions each accepting a char and an int as argument, and each returning a pointer to a pointer to void.

Now that you know what it is and how it's done... *don't* do it. Use typedefs to break your declarations into more manageable chunks. E.g.

```
typedef void **(*sillyFunction)(char, int);

sillyFunction (*weird)[6];
```

Comment: And nowadays, use `using` to map a name to a type.

Comment: And nowadays, use C++ :-P

Answer (score -1):

data[2] - an array of two integers

*data[2] - a pointer to an array of two integers

(*data[2]) - "

(*data[2])[2] - an array of 2 pointers to arrays of two integers.

Comment: Second item is not what you said.  Apart from the missing type (which you have assumed to be integers), it is an array of 2 pointers to integers.  The third is not C.  The fourth is probably correct.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm guessing maybe the quote is a ditto mark.  I still think the explanation leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an array:

```
int myArray[5];
int * myArrayPtr = myArray;
```

Would be perfectly reasonable. `myArray` without the brackets is a pointer to an `int`. When you add the brackets its like you deference the pointer `myArray`. You could write...

```
myArrayPtr[1] = 3;
```

Which is perfectly reasonable. Using parenthesis just makes things harder to read and understand IMO. And they show that people don't understand pointers, arrays, and pointer arithmetic, which is how the compiler or linker goes from one to the other. It seems with parenthesis you do get bounds checking though.