# C Reference Manual Appendix A - Meaning of declarators

Tags: c

While reading through the C reference manual, specifically Appendix A, I found the following statement

> In a declaration T D where D has the form ( D1 ), then the type of the identifier in D1 is the same as that of D. The parenthesis do not alter the type but may change the binding in complex declarators.

How can a declarator take a form of ( D1 ) and what is the difference in binding that is being referred here.

eg: `int a` is a proper declaration but what would `int (a)` mean?

Comment: It simply means that it won't change the end result by itself, but can change the order of evaluation. So `int a = 3;` and `int (a = 3);` are different (as you would expect, and the latter won't compile). But `int a` and `int (a)` are identical in meaning. You would probably only see real-world cases where brackets make a difference to the type (but both would compile) if you're using function pointers.

Comment: Here's an example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244680/what-do-parentheses-in-a-c-variable-declaration-mean

Comment: Thanks, the example explains it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int (a)` means exactly the same as `int a`. This is not a "complex declarator".

An example where it does make a difference is when declaring a function pointer:

```
int (*f)(float);
```

This means "`f` is a pointer to a function that takes a `float` and returns an `int`". Without the parentheses, it would read:

```
int *f(float);
```

This means "`f` is a function that takes a `float` and returns an `int*` (pointer to an `int`)". Something quite different indeed.

Try the website [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) (or the command line tool `cdecl`) to explain these:

```
cdecl> explain int (*f)(float);
declare f as pointer to function (float) returning int
cdecl> explain int *f(float);
declare f as function (float) returning pointer to int
```