# Error with pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

I have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char cad[] = "abc";

    char (*ptr)[1];

    ptr[0] = cad;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled throws me this error:

```
error #2168: Operands of '=' have incompatible types 'char [1]' and 'char *'.
```

Why this error occurs?

Comment: ptr[0] is a single character ... cad is a pointer ..

Comment: Could you clarify which part of the error you don't understand?

Comment: What are you trying to do? you should write ptr[0]=cad[0]

Comment: as should be the allocation

Comment: The error from clang is *"test.c:9:12: error: array type 'char [1]' is not assignable"*.  The compiler thinks `ptr[0]` is an array (because you told it so). Therefore, `ptr[0]` cannot be on the left side of an assignment operator.

Comment: Even if it compiled, you would have had *undefined behavior* when you tried to dereference the uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Why do you use  brackets on `char (*ptr)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/244692/669576

Comment: The real answer to this question is that `char (*ptr)[1]` is only useful if `ptr` points to a two-dimensional array. Since `cad` is a one-dimensional array, there's no valid use case for pointing `ptr` at `cad`.  (In addition, it's not useful to declare such a pointer with dimension `1`. The corresponding array declaration would be `array[N][1]` which is pointless nonsense).

Comment: @user3386109 Don't confuse the issue. It is like saying an `int*` is only useful if used to point to an array. But it can also be used to point to a single `int`. A pointer is a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza I disagree with your comment, and I disagree with your answer. Specifically, there is no condition under which `ptr[0] = anything` will compile. You seem to have overlooked that very important point. The assignment expression `ptr[0] = cad` is just flat-out wrong, period. `ptr[0]` cannot be on the left hand side of an assignment.

Comment: @user3386109 I am not overlooking it, I am explaining the compiler error to OP. I thought mentioning that arrays are unassignable was beyond the scope here, but I added it for completeness now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this error occurs?

Expression `ptr[0]` has type `char[1]` because `ptr` is declared lika pointer to array of type `char[1]`

```
char (*ptr)[1];
```

Expression `cad` has type `char *` and is equal to the address of the first character of array `cad`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus in the left side of the assignment statement

```
ptr[0] = cad;
```

there is an array of type `char[1]`. In the right side of the assignment there is a pointer of type `char *`. These types are incompatible and arrays do not have the assignment operator.

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char cad[] = "abc";

    char * ptr[1];

    ptr[0] = cad;

    // puts( ptr[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AniMenon Try to uncomment the commented statement.

Answer (score 1):

> Why this error occurs (*sic*)?

```
char cad[] = "abc";
```

Here, `cad` is a `char[4]` (containing characters `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'\0'`.)

```
char (*ptr)[1];
```

and here, `ptr` is a pointer to `char[1]`. So `ptr[0]` is a `char[1]`.

In the assignment expression

```
 ptr[0] = cad;
```

`cad` decays to `char*`. So you end up with incompatible operands, namely `char[1]` on the LHS and `char*` on the RHS, just like the compiler error message tells you.

Two further things worth mentioning:

- Arrays are not assignable, so there is no assignment expression for which `ptr[0] = ???;` is valid, given the type of `ptr`.
- There are no arrays of pointers in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char cad[] = "abc";
    int n = sizeof (cad) / sizeof (cad[0]);
    char (*ptr)[n];
    ptr = &cad;
    printf("%s",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
```

The problem with what you were doing was :

```
char cad[] = "abc";
char (*ptr)[1];
ptr[0] = cad;
```

char array `cad` has "abc", pointer array of type `char` and then you were trying to assign a single index of the pointer array(which is a `char`) with a `char[]`(that is `cad`), hence causing a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from the compiler is very clear.

type of `ptr` is `char (*)[1]`.
type of `ptr[0]` is `char [1]`.
`cad` decays to a pointer when used in `ptr[0] = cad`. Hence the type of the RHS is `char*`. You cannot assign a `char*` to a `char [1]`.

Also,

```
ptr[0] = ...;
```

leads to undefined behavior since memory has not been allocated for `ptr`.

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. You can do something like:

```
char (*ptr)[1] = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
ptr[0][0] = cad[0];
```

This will put the first character of `cad` in `ptr[0][0]`. However, `ptr[0]` is not a null terminated string. Hence, you won't be able to use it like a string.