# C pointer with 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C language, and I'm confused in 2D array pointer.

I have the following declaration

```
int a[3][5];
int *b[3][3];
int (*c)[3][5];
int *(d[3][5]);
int (*e[3])[5];
```

could anyone help me clarify

1. if there're valid declaration or not
2. the sizeof a,b,c,d,e (assume on 64-bit machine, address id 8 bytes)
3. what they point to
4. how to access the element in the 2D array

I'm totally confused about the usage of pointer in 2D array.....and I guess some of them are equivalent...but some might not be good practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do parentheses in a C variable declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244680/what-do-parentheses-in-a-c-variable-declaration-mean)

Comment: b and d would be the same if b were [3][5] instead of [3][3].  I assume you intended it to be [3][5]?

Comment: A 2D array is an array of 1D arrays. E.g an array of `rows` number of 1D arrays. `int *b[3][3]` is a 2D array of pointers to type `int`.  `int (*c)[3][5]`  is a *pointer to a 3x5 array of `int`* `int *(d[3][5]);` is the same as `*d[3][5]` and `int (*e[3])[5];` is an *array of pointers to 3 `int` (5 of them)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No:  `d` is the same as b (except for the 3 vs. 5) - the parentheses have no effect, and `e` is an array of 3 pointers, which point to arrays of 5 ints.  In particular, sizeof(e) is 3*8 = 24.

Comment: Good catch Tom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These

```
int a[3][5];
int *b[3][5];
```

(I think you mean indeed `int *b[3][5]` instead of `int *b[3][3]` as it is written in your question)
two declarations of two-dimensional arrays.

Elements of the first array have type `int`.
Elements of the second array have type `int *`.

To access elements of the arrays you can use for example subscripting like

`a[i][j]` or `b[i][j]` where `i` is an index in the range `[0,3)` and `j` is an index in the range [0, 5).

For the second array to access objects pointed to by the elements of the array you can use expressions like `*b[i][j]`

`sizeof( a )` is equal to `3 * sizeof( int[5] )` that in turn is equal to `3 * 5 * sizeof( int )`.

`sizeof( b )` is equal to `3 * sizeof( int *[5] )` that in turn is equal to `3 * 5 * sizeof( int *)`.

This

```
int (*c)[3][5];
```

is a declaration of a pointer to a two-dimensional array of the type `int[3][5]`.
You can write for example

```
int (*c)[3][5] = &a;
```

where `a` is the two-dimensional array declared above.

To access elements of the pointed array you can use this syntax

```
( *c )[i][j]
```

This

```
int *(d[3][5]);
```

a declaration of a two-dimensional array elements of which have type `int *`.
This declaration is equivalent to the declaration shown above that is to

```
int *b[3][5];
```

You may enclose declarators in parentheses. So you could even write the declaration of the array `d` like

```
int * (((d)[3])[5]);
```

This

```
int (*e[3])[5];
```

is a declaration of an array with 3 elements of pointers to arrays of the type `int[5]`.
Using the typedef

```
typedef int T[5];
```

the array declaration can be rewritten like

```
T * e[3];
```

Here a demonstrative program that shows how elements of the array `e` can be accessed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a1[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int a2[5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int a3[5] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };

    int(*e[3])[5] = { &a1, &a2, &a3 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( e ) / sizeof( *e ); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(*e[i]) / sizeof(**e[i]); j++)
        {
            printf( "%3d ", ( *e[i] )[j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
  1   2   3   4   5
 10  20  30  40  50
100 200 300 400 500
```

Comment: thanks for very detailed explanation! But is there any rules to parse the pointer declaration? I don't want to learn by rote. Maybe for a C expert it's obvious but for me it's hard to understand.

Comment: @ZiqiLiu Just substitute the left most array to a pointer. For example int ( a[n1] )[n2][n3]; int ( *p )[n2][n3] = a;

Comment: Does this declaration set aside the memory space as well? Does it create space in memory for 3 int array pointers and y number of integers at each pointer? If so, how would this memory be organised?

Comment: @etienz There is created an array of three pointers an nothing more.